# Как сделать проверку на Null?

Tags: c#, linq

У меня есть такой код на Linq

```
int rowInd = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
var showPhone = db.phones.First(ph => ph.person_id == rowInd);
```

И если в базе ничего нет, то он выкидывает ошибку и все. Я перепробовал разные способы и ничего не помогло. Где я не прав?

Вот так работает

```
var showPhone = String.Empty;
if ((db.phones.FirstOrDefault(ph => ph.person_id == rowInd) == null)) 
{
    showPhone = ""; 
} 
else 
{ 
    showPhone = db.phones.FirstOrDefault(ph => ph.person_id == rowInd).phone1; 
}
```

код ужасен. Как его можно сократить?

Comment: Сделай сначала проверку, что размер `db.phones` > 0.

Comment: Не ну он точно больше нуля. Просто в некоторых местах нет записей и у меня выпадает ошибка

Comment: Выкидывает, когда нет записей, сделать эту проверку, первое что в голову пришло. Посмотри что в памяти творится в режиме debug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можете так сделать например:

```
var tmp = phones.FirstOrDefault(ph => ph.person_id == rowInd);
var showPhone = tmp == null ? "" : tmp.phone1;
```

или даже так, если есть поддержка C# 6:

```
  var tmp = phones.FirstOrDefault(ph => ph.person_id == rowInd);
  var showPhone = tmp?.phone1 ??  "";
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
var showPhone = "";
var phone = db.phones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.person_id == rowInd);
if (phone != null) 
{
    showPhone = phone.phone1; 
}
```

для C# 6:

```
var phone = db.phones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.person_id == rowInd);
var showPhone = phone?.phone1 ?? "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать проверку на Null

```
if (Convert.IsDbNull(phone) == false) 
{
    showPhone = phone.phone1; 
}
```